# How to add numbers in link (loop)

Tags: python, loops, web, web-scraping, count

I'm writing a script where I try to scrape data from json files. The website link structure looks like this:

> https://go.lime-go.com/395012/Organization/pase1009/

I want the Python script to go through a certain number and try to visit them. For example, right now the link is at pase1009. After the script has visited this link I want it to go to pase1010 and so on.

I'm really new to Python and trying to learn how to use loops, count, etc. but don't get it.

My PY code:

```
    rlista = "https://go.lime-go.com/395012/Organization/pase1009/getEmployees"
    page = self.driver.get(rlista)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Best regards,
Tobias

Comment: Thats quite basic stuff, you should consider reading some tutorials (google for python loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine several strings to one with the `+`-operator.
So you could save your base link in a variable and add the number afterwards in the loop.
Would look something like this:

```
baseLink = "https://your-link.com/any/further/stuff/pase"

for k in range(1000,1010,2):
    link = baseLink + str(k)
    print(link)
```

There your links would be

- https://your-link.com/any/further/stuff/pase1000
- https://your-link.com/any/further/stuff/pase1002
- https://your-link.com/any/further/stuff/pase1004
- https://your-link.com/any/further/stuff/pase1006
- https://your-link.com/any/further/stuff/pase1008

as k will start with 1000, increment by 2 and stop before 1010 (`range(start, stop, increment)`).